# How to get the journal/notes for a Redmine issue in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, redmine

I am using the redmine_client (0.0.1) gem to lookup issues in Redmine but get an error when I do something like this:

puts issue.journals.inspect # error - undefined method `journals' for #

I am following this example: https://gist.github.com/552610

Any idea what might be the problem? All the other fields work fine except for journal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Journals is an association to an Array of Journal objects. I don't know if I've added Journal support to that gem yet (I don't use it much anymore). Try forking the gem and adding a new journal.rb class like issue.rb.